# Make a full background image full site

Tags: html, css

I have a background image that I need to be at the bottom of the entire page is the following:

```
.background-div {
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100%;
 background-image: url('./assets/pattern.png');
 background-repeat: repeat;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: 40%;
 }
```

but in a view there is a moment that a data fetch is made that occupies half of the view and the background is left in half I do not know how to solve it when I place 100vh if the content is a lot it is cut, and if I put 100% it is cut in half while fetching the data

Comment: Could you provide more code?

Comment: `background-size: cover;`?

Comment: Please see [ask] and provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can make full page image like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.background-div {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("assets/pattern.jpg");

  /* Full height */
  height: 100%; 
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="background-div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

(source: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_full_page.asp)